# How to properly block and clear notifications in android?

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have made a notification blocker app with java around 6 months ago now. [Here](https://github.com/EthanRodrigo/NotificationBlocker) is the source code. It all works fine, the notifications are blocked and stored in the DB also. Yet there's one issue. I still can see the notifications coming as this image shows.[image: As in this image]

Since this is a notification blocker, this is not going to be very accurate. Therefore I need a way to block notifications from the view of the user in android.
If you have ever used `focused mode`, that is what I want. To block all the notifications and when they are unblocked again, I want to show them in the status bar. Any idea how to tackle this bug?

Comment: I suggest you to add in the question the code you tried, and explain the issue of the given one

Comment: @Elikill58 I have added the github link (https://github.com/EthanRodrigo/NotificationBlocker) to the project as it's really big. And the problem is that notifications are still showing even when they are blocked.